# Golang detect if in focus or minimized

Tags: go

How would I go about detecting if my go CLI program is in focus or minimized?

Current program based off https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui

I require the functionality as it is a chat program and I would like to send OS notifications but only when the program is not in focus or is minimized.

Your help/direction is much appreciated as of right now unsure where to start.

Comment: you mean for a gui application, a cli ? which platform ? which framework ?

Comment: That depends on a number of things, including OS, GUI framework (I assume it's a GUI application, otherwise focus wouldn't really be relevant?), etc.

Comment: @mh-cbon sorry I was just thinking about specifying that and you beat me too it. I've got CLI program using GOCUI.

Comment: @rob74 Linux and Windows would be great. I'm using gocui as a gui for my CLI program. It's a chat app so I would like to send an OS notification if the program is not in view or minimized.

Comment: A CLI program has no concept of "focus". It doesn't even know if it's running in a window.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible from the library itself. A command line program does now have a focus, but the terminal program it is running in.

To implement that (if possible at all) would be dependent on os, window manager etc.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll dig deeper to see if there are any API calls I can make to determine this.

Answer (score 2):

To refine the [answer](/a/56080185/720999) provided by [@mbuechmann](/users/1360318/mbuechmann), I suggest the OP not to try to resort to APIs etc.

The reasoning is simple.
"Contemporary" users are used to running programs in terminal emulators which are typically presented as separate *windows,* and so the users naturally think of these programs as not really different from GUI apps.

But the reality is different: a terminal emulator—whether graphical or not (for instance, so-called ["virtual consoles" provided by the Linux kernel running on an x86/amd64 hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console) are terminal emulators as well)—really emulates a typical work session on a real [hardware terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal), and there, a program would work in foreground solely, and the only means of "switching" to another program was using the [shell's job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) (those `jobs`, `bg` and `fg` commands).

In other words, the whole concept of a program working in a terminal has an inbuilt assumption that the terminal is always "foreground"—since at the time the concept was developed, a terminal was a physical device.

Now please also consider that "terminal emulation" may be more pervasive on a contemporary system than you might think: `screen` and `tmux` on a Unix-like OS are multiplexing terminal emulators—which may themselves be run in a terminal emulator, and a console window on Windows™ may be considered to be a terminal emulator of sorts as well.

So, "resorting to APIs" have several *technical* problems:

- Terminal emulation tries to actually decouple the program which uses this facility from being aware of how the facility is actually provided.

  To put it simple, there's, say, no easy way on X Window System, to know what window is used by the terminal emulator running your program.
- You'd need to cover diverse set of APIs in order for your program to still be useful: X Window System on Unix-like systems, Mac OS, Windows™. And contemporary GUI stacks running on Linux tend to be switching to Wayland instead of X.
- In certain cases, like running a program in a "nested" terminal emulation sessions (for example, a pane in a "window" of a `tmux` running in `xterm`), figuring out such facts about the environment might be next to impossible.

And still the crucial problem is that if your program really *needs* to know whether it's focused or not, it actually *wants* to be aware about the concepts currently hardly accessible to it. I mean, it wants to be GUI. And if so, just make it GUI.

In fact, it may be simpler than you think. The core of your program might still be a CLI app with a thin GUI wrapper around it which uses any sort of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to talk with the app (which might be two-way, if needed).
The simplest is to write some (usually line-wise) data to the program's standard input.